# I cannot find a way to connect all points of a grid to form triangles, without any crossing

Tags: python, geometry

In order to solve this I've tried many things but they all ended up failing because I couldn't come up with ways to not have past points used or lines crossing... So I don't have any code to show appart from the list of points used.

```
points = [
    (5, 6, 'A'),
    (5, -8, 'B'),
    (-2, 2, 'C'),
    (-10, 4, 'D'),
    (8, 1, 'E'),
    (-8, 8, 'F'),
    (2, 7, 'G')
]
```

I would want a list containing the points of all triangles possible, like this:

```
triangles = [[A, B, C], [B, C, D], ...]
```

[image: screenshot]

I only want a suggestion on how to achieve this
I hope this is clear enough to get an idea of what I'd like to achieve...

Comment: this isn't a programming issue

Comment: well I cannot figure out how I could code it to find them for any set of points, sorry if I'm not clear... I've never tried posting anything on here

Comment: You say you have tried many things; even if those methods did not work, try to explain them or show us your attempts. Right now you are asking somebody to code this for you, and that is not what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: Using you sample data what should your code output and/or return? Please add the desired result to your question using [Edit].

Comment: It looks like you might be trying to do a Delaunay Triangulation on a set of points. You might be able to do that by getting a Dirichlet tessellation and then taking the dual?

Comment: I'd like insight into how It would be possible to do this, like a suggestion... I'd love to do the coding myself; besides I removed all my failed attempts which I realise now was a mistake

Comment: [This paper](https://www.newcastle.edu.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0017/22508/13_A-fast-algorithm-for-constructing-Delaunay-triangulations-in-the-plane.pdf) has some algorithms for delaunay triangulations. I'll drop some pseudocode in an answer in a sec

Comment: @JakobLovern I had never heard of this but yeah I think this could work! I'm going to have a go and if I succeed I'll post it here

Comment: hmm, actually I skimmed that paper and it's *really* dense. Try [this](https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs235/Delaunay) instead. It's still kinda heavy but it's at least legible

Comment: Additionally it looks like there's a [scipy function to do this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html) if you're just looking for a solution

Comment: That is actually it! Sorry for nor being too clear on what I needed... It's my first time posting a question onto here. Thanks for your help! @JakobLovern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use [`scipy.spatial.Delaunay`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html). The following example computes the Delaunay triangulation of four points (taken directly from linked page):

```py
points = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1.1], [1, 0], [1, 1]])
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
tri = Delaunay(points)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.triplot(points[:,0], points[:,1], tri.simplices)
plt.plot(points[:,0], points[:,1], 'o')
plt.show()
```

[image: Delaunay triangulation of four points]

I won't pretend to understand what's actually going on, but if you know more about np/scipy you should be able to get something useful out.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried searching this online for a while and nothing of this sort came up.